# excel How to make the "+"symbol at the left side of the outline

Tags: c#, excel, range, outline

I am using `range.group` method from the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`
and it works to group up the columns or rows as the outline level in the Excel document;
but there comes the question of how to set the `"+"`symbol at the left side, but not it's default position at the right side according to the last columns or rows.

What method is used for controlling the direction and how to use this method. It would be best if that's an example,.

Comment: why do u want to Keep "+" symbol on the Left side ?

Comment: Sorry,but i did not understand your question and actually what u want to do ? IF u can edit it write in better way that would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry,my english is not good.I want to make the "+" symbol of outline level at the left side instead of it's default setting at the right side.

Comment: may be this codes will help to understand.
m_objSheet.get_Range(j + ":" + Convert.ToInt32(rg.Cells.Row-1), Missing.Value).Rows.Group(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
m_objSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1);

Comment: are u refering symbo **+** which is used to concatenate strings  (j + ":" + Convert.ToInt32(rg.Cells.Row-1),  ?

Comment: @singa: Show us an example, so we don't have to guess what you're trying to do.   @Sangram: Are "u" writing from "ur" 12 year old mobile phone?!

Comment: range = m_objSheet.get_Range("A1:"+maxcolcount+1,Missing.Value);
                    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cg in range)
                    {
                        if (cg.Value2 != null)
                        {
                            if (cg.Value2.ToString().EndsWith("-非优质店"))
                            {
                                m_objSheet.get_Range(transformvalue(cg.Column - 1) + ":" + transformvalue(cg.Column), Missing.Value).Columns.Group(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); }               }                    }

Comment: this was part of my codes.
if (cg.Value2.ToString().EndsWith("-非优质店")) { m_objSheet.get_Range(transformvalue(cg.Column - 1) + ":" + transformvalue(cg.Column), Missing.Value).Columns.Group(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
this statement will outline the columns that match my codition in the excel sheet.and we open the excel file,we can see the "+"symbol at the top of the sheet.the symbol form at the last column which match my codition,i wanna it form at the first column which matched.

Answer (score 5):

In excel: Data/Group and Outline/Settings...

In code:

```
range.Group(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

//for rows
worksheet.Outline.SummaryRow = Excel.XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryAbove;

//for columns
worksheet.Outline.SummaryColumn = Excel.XlSummaryColumn.xlSummaryOnLeft;
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12276/A-little-known-trick-to-help-with-MS-Office-automa

Answer (score 2):

To apply it on the left without using VBA:

In Excel: Data-> Outline. Click on the arrow on the bottom right corner of the ribbon (The arrow is pointing down right.)

It will open the Outline Settings.

Untick "Summary column on the right on the right of detail."
Click Apply Styles.